# How is respiration an unbalanced equation

Tags: biochemistry, cellular-respiration

The equation for respiration is C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub>+6O<sub>2</sub>→6CO<sub>2</sub>+6H<sub>2</sub>O+36ATP. The chemical formula for ATP is C<sub>10</sub>H<sub>16</sub>N<sub>5</sub>O<sub>13</sub>P<sub>3</sub>. How is this possible, since it violates the law of conservation of mass because it is unbalanced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ATP is not actually produced from the respiration. It comes from ADP and free phosphate ions.

The production of ATP in cellular respiration happens in all parts of a series of chain reactions, and you can read more about those here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_respiration#Aerobic_respiration